# Problem with @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, date, jpa-2.0

Hi I want to map a field in my Java class

```
@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

to a field in my table :

```
date_of_birth date,
```

but now when I try to run my application I got an exception :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong 
column type in public.users for column date_of_birth.
 Found: date, expected: timestamp
```

This is my configuration file :

```
dataSource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
hibernate.show_sql=false
```

What can be the problem here?

Thanks
Dawid

Comment: Looks like `@Temporal` is ignored for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think your column type in the database needs to be `timestamp` instead of `date`. But that may not be what you want, seeing as you are storing a date of birth.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a bit old, but was looking for some @Temporal usage and came accross your question of 5 years old already ;).

Problem is obvious :) System error stack trace is telling you:

> " Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong  column type in
> public.users for column date_of_birth.  Found: date, expected:
> timestamp "

You are trying to put Date object into your DB that expects a TimeStamp one -> your TemporalType is of DATE type and DB Expects to be of TIMESTAMP

> @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
>
> @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
>
> private Date dateOfBirth;

Comment: I don't know if this is a joke - we all are able to read. The field is defined as date in his Table. He used java.util.Date and TemporalType.DATE in his Java sources. Why is the database expecting Timestamp when there is always date defined?

Comment: @Del-Pedro Well I think a bit proactive thinking before down voting or expressing such strong dissing for no obvious fact to backup. Question was "What can be the problem". I did provide the answer. reason why, is hard without DB schema as well.

Comment: @DelPedro To answer you question: java.sql.Timestamp extends java.util.Date and adds a nanoseconds field. The equals implementation for Timestamp does violate symmetry and can cause erratic behavior if Timestamp and Date objects are used for same or intermixed. They are not equal.